# Method runs for every instance of the method

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to set my ASP row and cell color based off my method in my data class. I have the color set and the method running. The method returns `true` or `false` based on the conditions below. How can I prevent the method from running multiple times?

For instance, it runs once and returns correctly then it runs again with `""` in the `lineNum` and `brandNum` fields with the pack count as the same number as the first run. It processed to run once for every instance of my method call. Then when I actually call the method again it runs everything again. Why is it running more than once and how can I fix this?

```
output:
lineNum:123 brandNum:456 packCount:15
second run (not asked for)
lineNum:"" brandNum:"" packCount:15
```

Method to determine if true:

```
SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[]
{
    new SqlParameter("@GenNum6", itemNum),
    new SqlParameter("@GenTxt9", brandNum)
};

try
{
    reader = App_Code.DBHelper.executeQuery(dbConn,
        sqlString.ToString(), parameters);
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            PackCount = reader["PackCount"].ToString();
        }
    }
    reader.Close();
    reader.Dispose();
    dbConn.Close();
    dbConn.Dispose();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    if (dbConn != null)
    {
        try { dbConn.Close(); dbConn.Dispose(); }
        catch { }
    }
    if (reader != null)
    {
        try { reader.Close(); reader.Dispose(); }
        catch { }
    }
}

if (Convert.ToInt32(PackCount) <= 12)
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Call:

```
if (lineData.PacksLeft1(L1.Text,L2.Text))
{
    myTable.Rows[1].Cells[0].BgColor = "#FE2E2E";
    myTable.Rows[1].Cells[1].BgColor = "#FE2E2E";
    myTable.Rows[1].Cells[2].BgColor = "#FE2E2E";
    myTable.Rows[1].Cells[3].BgColor = "#FE2E2E";
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that is calling this. Also, if the parameters never changed, consider memoising the result to avoid needless expensive calls to the database. Also, review the call stack to see where the second call is coming from. It might be coming from inside a control or some code that isn't yours, which may in turn be a misunderstanding about how that code is supposed to work, I constantly do this with WinForms events.

Comment: I think we need some more information, here.  This is the code that is running, but it sound from your description that the error would be in the code that is calling this

Comment: Edit made! I apologize for lack of info.

Comment: hmm assuming the called method is `PacksLeft1`, taking `itemNum` and `brandNum` as the two arguments maybe what's happening is that your reader is processing two rows, the second row being empty, or containing no columns with the appropriate names.  Especially with SQL Server, it's possible for a stored procedure to return more than one dataset.  Hard to say without seeing the rest of it, though

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the finally statement as it performs the same action that is performed in the try statement.  I believe that after seeing this piece, if you go back through where it is being called from, you may have it running in a try catch, doing the exact same thing.  I would suggest taking the

```
reader.Close();
reader.Dispose();
dbConn.Close();
dbConn.Dispose();
```

out of the try block and leaving the finally statement.  This way, no matter the outcome, these items are performed.

Finally is only used when you want the code to run something after it has preformed the try statement.  Such as:

```
Try{
   //Try this statement, if it works, run it.
}
catch{
   //error occurred
}
finally{
  //run this code whether the try failed or not.
}
```